# JSDoc and class nested objects

Tags: jsdoc

So I've searched and found a lot on this topic, but nothing that seems to directly address my question or if it does it either pretty much requires me to basically reimplement my object definition in JSDoc (eg @typedef, which strikes me as duplication of effort and makes two places to maintain 'code') or does it in a way that produces weird documentation (eg, using namespaces).

So if I have a classes with a nested object (say, a dictionary lookup), I can't seem to get its members to appear automagically in JSDoc as part of the class documentation.  Instead, they all appear as individual entries in the Global section.

Example:

```
/**
 * An example class
 * @class
 */
class MyClass {
  /** An object literal */
  myObjectLiteral = {
    /** property 1, ya know? */
    objProperty1: "moo",
    /** property 2, baby! */
    objProperty2: "goo"
  }
}
```

MyClass appears as a class with myObjectLiteral as a member, but objProperty1 and objProperty2 appear as entries in the Global section.

Is there an elegant way to get JSDoc to include the object literal and its properties in the class documentation?  I thought that using @memberof might do the trick, but it didn't seem to work (tho I may have effed up the syntax).

Comment: Please share if/when you've been able to get to something useful on your own, I've the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @DavideBarranca but I never found a good solution.